Protecting Senty Auth Token from being exposed in app bundle
I am building a react native app using Jenkins. My Sentry Auth Token is stored in a .env file. When I build the iOS or android app this Sentry Auth Token is exposed in the bundle. I would like to prevent this from being exposed to app bundle. I only need this in build time to upload the symbol maps. This should not be available in runtime or in the built app. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

You could use a file with the secret token, placed in secure directory,  and ensure a script is run as part of the bundle process.
An example to set env variables
